# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow with very small values

Tags: c#, math

I have an exception saying that 'arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow' although I made a debugging and the values of my variables are small and don't even exceed 10! I really don't know what to do.

```
bool go = true;
int columns;
int rows;
columns = rows = 0;
int incrementer = 2;
while(go)
{
    columns = incrementer;
    if(cipherText.Length%columns!=0)
    {
        incrementer++;
        continue;
    }
    rows = cipherText.Length / columns;
    char[,] matrix = new char[rows, columns];
}
```

The error is in the last line. The debugging showed that the values of 'rows' and 'columns' are somthing like 3, 5 and so on. How do these values exceed the limit of data type 'int'?

Comment: What is `cipherText.Length` ?

Comment: can you show runnable code that actual shows the problem you're reporting? the current code loops forever (`go` never becomes `false`, and there is no `break`) without any output, and we don't have any example values of `cipherText` to test with; I can't get it to show the behaviour you're citing

Comment: There's another interesting issue here, which is that your code will loop forever as son as `incrementer` reaches a value which divides into `cipherText.Length`. As soon as this happens, `cipherText.Length % columns` will be 0, and you won't hit the line `incrementer++`. Once this happens, `incrementer` will never change value again, which means that `columns` will never change value, and so the loop will just keep happening and not changing anything.

Comment: The only way to avoid this is if `cipherText.Length` is 1. Because `incrementer` starts at 2, this means that `cipherText.Length%columns` will always return 2, which means that you'll keep hitting that `incrementer++` line. Once this reaches `int.MaxValue` this would normally just overflow without an exception: to get an exception, you must be compiling with checked arithmetic enabled, i.e. `<CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>` set in your .csproj

Answer (score 3):

You said it yourself:

> The debugging showed that the values of 'rows' and 'columns' are somthing like 3, 5 and so on.

When checking your code, I see:

```
bool go = true;
...
while (go)
{
    ...
}
```

Nowhere in your loop you are saying `go=false`. So, your loop is starting with 3, 5, and so on, and on, and on, and on, and on, ... until the values get so large that an overflow is reached.

You need to implement a criteria that does something like:

```
while (go)
{
    ...
    if (criteria)
        go = false;
}
```

... and obviously your criteria needs to be realistic enough to stop your loop in time, before the overflow is reached.